# Hide Resource ID's from SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I have developed one SDK containig a layout with some sensitive input fields.
This SDK will be provided to third party App.
Everything is working fine.

Problem is,
I don't want third party App to fetch any of information from the input fields. But while using that SDK(.aar  file) **he can get the resource id's of those SDK input fields**.

What can be done to prevent the resource id's from been exposed.

Code used in third party app to integrate the SDK,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package_name", "com.package_name.class_name"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want third party App to fetch any of information from the input fields

It is code in their app. They can get at whatever they want.

> What can be done to prevent the resource id's from been exposed.

If by "exposed", you mean "available at compile time as simple `R` constants", you can [whitelist the IDs that should be public](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources), and the build tools will hide the remainder.

Note that this will not stop an interested party from accessing those fields from within their own process. It will merely add a few minutes to the development process.

Comment: while creating a public directory, public.xml is not valid name error is displaying

Comment: @NikhilSawant: I do not see where [the documentation that I linked to](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources) refers to creating "a public directory". It advises you to create a `res/values/public.xml` file and to list public resources in there.

Comment: I added a public tag inside string,xml and it worked